# Check if alias exists?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony-2.3, query-builder

How I could check if the alias is already defined?

There is no method for check this.

Thats not working because I got only the ROOT alias and no join aliases.

```
/** @var $query \Doctrine\ORM\QueryBuilder */
$query->getRootAliases()
```

The parts is another invalid option for me...

```
$query->getDQLPart()
```

Returns only the parts like "select, from, etc.".

And thats the error I would "ignore".

```
[Semantical Error] line 0, col 254 near '_user LEFT': Error: '_user' is already defined.
```

**How could I check if the alias exists?**

Comment: The query builder keeps track of join aliases but doesn't expose them: https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/6e64cc101adcd46c4668f6c2927ac648238ab260/lib/Doctrine/ORM/QueryBuilder.php#L119

Answer (score 23):

You could use PHP native `in_array` function to check if the value exists in the array or not.

```
in_array($alias, $qb->getAllAliases())
```

Comment: `getAllAliases` is available from Doctrine 2.5, for anyone else who comes across this

Comment: ``$queryBuilder->getRootAliases()``

Answer (score 9):

You get this error because you're trying to join with an already defined alias.

A solution would be to check join DQL parts. In your repository method you could do something like this:

```
$joinDqlParts = $queryBuilder->getDQLParts()['join'];
$aliasAlreadyExists = false;

/* @var $join Query\Expr\Join */
foreach ($joinDqlParts as $joins) {
    foreach ($joins as $join) {
        if ($join->getAlias() === '_user') {
            $aliasAlreadyExists = true;
            break 2;
        }
    }
}

if ($aliasAlreadyExists === false) {
    $queryBuilder->innerJoin('parenttable._user', '_user')

}
```

So you only join if you didn't joined already.